# How to transfer data between unrelated pages?Angular 8

Tags: angular

I am developing an application on Angular 8. I make it multi-page, and I pass the parameters through Router. I need to transfer data from one page to another, how can I do this if my pages are not connected in any way? All pages are loaded via router-outlet.

Is it bad practice that I don't use parent.component -> child.component nesting?

Because in the future I will need to transfer data deep into the applications for my library.Example 
`<my-library [data]="data"></my-library>`

Routes

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'progects/:id', component: ProgectsComponent},
  { path: 'progect/:id', component: ProgectComponent},
  { path: 'polls', component: PollsComponent},
  { path: 'poll/:id', component: PollComponent},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }
];
```

Comment: You can use a service for that. You woudl define a Subject for example and every time you have to pass data your would emit that with `yourSubject.next()` and listen to it on your other pages where you subscribed to it.

Comment: angular provides different ways for component interaction please read here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: You can store it in the local or session storage as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to transfer data between different components. The choice of selection may vary based on what your goal is.

1. Parent to child: `@Input()` decorator
2. Child to parent: `@Output()` and `EventEmitter`
3. Child to parent: `@ViewChild()`
4. Unrelated component: Sharing Data as a **service**.

You need to create a service for sharing data between different components.

You can have a look at this [**article**](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/) to get started.

Comment: But can a service exchange data with a closed page? Shouldn't the exchange components be on the same page?

Comment: Why would you approach sharing data between a closed page and an open page? A closed page doesn't have any data. Data comes when you open that page. So you should just call the same service(if you are using any) in your opened component that you are calling for your closed component.

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped! Now, I need to somehow transfer the data to my service. For example, I will have a library where attributes will be written, for example <my-library [id-region]="12312313"></my-library> .
How do I pass id-region to my service?
So that I can use this id throughout the project.

Comment: `<my-library [id-region]="12312313"></my-library>` this is the format of parent to child interaction. You can do that only using `@Input()` decorator. No need to use service for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

**You have the three ways for transfer data.**

> 1. Using Router.navigate()

```
this.router.navigate(['/polls'], {
  state: {
      data: "some data which you want"
  }
});
```

and get it into PollsComponent by `this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state`
but `YOU NEED TO GET THE DATA INTO CONSTRUCTOR of PollsComponent`, on angular lifehooks it is not exists, because it is exists until router event `NavigationEnd`.

> 2. Using queryParams

```
this.router.navigate(['/polls'], {
  queryParams: {
      data: "some data which you want"
  }
});
```

and get it into PollsComponent by `ActivatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams`

> 3. Using Singleton service
>      just have a service which is `providedIn: root` and store it by property

But the data will lost after refresh or when user deletes the queryParams (#2 way).

### Note:

I will recommend you to use params like `poll/:id`
and get id into PollComponent onInit method and using that Id get data from. In this case, you can get `:id` in `ActivatedRoute.snapshot.params`